# Pandas: Cómo filtrar y reorganizar una tabla

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Intento trabajar unos datos que tengo importados desde YahooFinanzas con este codigo:

```
start = pd.Timestamp ('1950-01-01')
end = pd.Timestamp ('2016-01-04')
f = web.DataReader ('^GSPC', 'yahoo',start,end)
```

obtengo estos datos

```
f.tail()
```

[image: datos yahoofinanzas]

Bien. En la primera columna tengo el campo fecha. Lo que necesito es filtrar por determinados meses. Por ejemplo, todos los meses de noviembre desde 1950 hasta 2016 el valor de Close, y reordenar la tabla para obtener un formato como el de la siguiente imagen con el que pueda trabajar:
[image: tabla]
Tengo en cuenta que para determinadas fechas no tendre ningún valor y será Nan.

He intentado con

```
f.loc[f.index.month == 11,'Close']
```

pero luego no se cómo dar el reordenamiento que necesito
¿Alguien sabe alguna forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aclaro que no soy experto en Pandas y puede que existan mejores formas de hacer esto. Dicho esto puedes hacer algo así:

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web


start = pd.Timestamp ('1950-01-01')
end = pd.Timestamp ('2016-01-04')
f = web.DataReader ('^GSPC', 'yahoo',start,end)

f = f.loc[f.index.month == 11,'Close']

#Creamos un data-frame vacío solo con las columnas(dia/mes) y los indices(años) 
inicio = pd.Timestamp('2016-11-01')
final = pd.Timestamp('2016-11-30')
columnas = [datetime.strftime(timestamp, '%d/%m') for timestamp in pd.date_range(inicio, final, freq="1D")]
indices = [datetime.strftime(timestamp, '%Y') for timestamp in pd.date_range(start, end, freq="A")]
df = pd.DataFrame(index=indices, columns=columnas)
df = df.astype(np.float) 


#LLenamos el data-frame nuevo con los datos que nos retorna el filtrado con .loc
for fecha in f.index:
    fila = str(fecha.year)
    columna = datetime.strftime(fecha, '%d/%m')
    df.set_value(fila, columna, f[fecha])
```

Como resultado si hacemos:

```
df.tail()
```

Obtenemos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Perfecto. Gracias